# How to solve this simultaneous differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How should I solve this simultaneous differential equations$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{dy}{dt} = -x+y+4t^2+10t+3 \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = -x-y+8e^{2t}
\end{cases}$$

where $x=x(t),y=y(t)$.

I would like to solve for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$.
Can  someone help me to solve ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Substitute for $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the first equation using the second. Then find $y=y(t)$ and use the second equation to find $x(t)$.

Comment: What have you done? Are you stuck on some step? Is your calculation wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the system is

\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}-\frac{dy}{dt} = -x+y+4t^2+10t+3 \\
\frac{dx}{dt} = -x-y+8e^{2t}
\end{cases}

Putting the value of $\frac{dx}{dt}$ in the first equation we have,

$\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=8e^{2t}-4t^2-10t-3$

This is a first order differential equation, so multiplying both sides by integrating factor (I.F) is $e^{2t}$ and then integrating  we have

$y e^{2t}= \int (8e^{4t}-4t^2  e^{2t}-10t e^{2t}-3 e^{2t})dt$

$\implies y e^{2t}= 2e^{4t}-4[\frac{t^2}{2}e^{2t}-\int te^{2t}dt]-\int 10t e^{2t}dt - \frac{3}{2}e^{2t}$

$\implies y e^{2t}= 2e^{4t}-2{t^2}e^{2t}-\int 6t e^{2t}dt - \frac{3}{2}e^{2t}$

$\implies y e^{2t}= 2e^{4t}-2{t^2}e^{2t}- 6[\frac{t}{2}e^{2t}-\frac{e^{2t}}{4} ] - \frac{3}{2}e^{2t} + c$, where $c$ is integrating constant.

$\implies y e^{2t}= 2e^{4t}-2{t^2}e^{2t}- 3{t}e^{2t}+c$

$\implies y = 2e^{2t}-2{t^2}- 3{t}+c e^{-2t}$

Now $\frac{dx}{dt} = -x-y+8e^{2t}\implies \frac{dx}{dt} + x = 2{t^2}+ 3{t}-c e^{-2t}+6e^{2t}$

This is again a first order differential equation, so multiplying both sides by integrating factor (I.F) is $e^{t}$ and then integrating  we have

$xe^t=\int [2{t^2}e^t+ 3{t}e^t-c e^{-t}+6e^{3t}]dt$

$\implies xe^t= 2[t^2 e^{t}-\int 2t e^{t} dt] + \int [3{t}e^t-c e^{-t}+6e^{3t}]dt$

$\implies x e^t = 2 t^2 e^t-\int t e^{t} dt + c e^{-t}+2 e^{3t}$

$\implies  x e^t = 2 t^2 e^t-[t e^t-e^t] + c e^{-t}+2 e^{3t}+d$, $d$ is integrating constant.

$\implies x=2 e^{2t}+2t^2-t+1+c e^{-2t}+de^{-t}$

Comment: Why is the I.F be $e^{2t}$? Not $e^{-2t}$?

Comment: Do you know what is an integrating factor and how it calculated? If not, then find the link "https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor"